# Does Aws codebuild manage iOS enviroments?

Tags: ios, iphone, continuous-integration, aws-codebuild

Is it possible to build and run unit test of iOS in AWS CodeBuild?,
I did some research but found not much, just saw some examples with fastlane or travis.

Comment: Are you using one of the supported frameworks they support as listed in the FAQ? https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/faqs/?nc=sn&loc=5

Answer (score 3):

No, iOS builds are not supported in CodeBuild today. Only Linux and Windows build environments are supported.